# How to fix color profile issue in Vista on headless PC?

Tags: windows-vista, remote-desktop, color-profiles

In Vista (and W7 too?), there is a known issue that can crop up which impacts the color profile when viewing images in Photo Gallery (and elsewhere).  The MS solution ([see here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/photo-viewer-puts-a-yellow-cast-over-all-pictures/7e87f98a-0bcf-462c-8167-93bac4bbed1d)) requires setting the profile for your display device.

My problem is that I'm accessing my PC via RDT, so there is no display device listed in either method for me to configure.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to this page and run the fixit tool.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939395

Comment: I had high hopes for that, but it didn't fix it.  I still think the issue is hard to fix because there is no monitor connected to the box, so the normal methods for color profile management won't work.

Comment: If it is headless why is the color profile an issue?

Comment: The box is remote.  I RDT into it and so still would like the color support to work properly.

Comment: I suppose there is no way to get someone to temporarily connect a monitoe on the other end?

Comment: I can definitely do that, and I'll rerun the fixit app.  Hopefully the configuration will remain for whatever code runs that interacts between RDT and apps like Photo Gallery (FYI - images appear fine in IE and other browsers).